# Can I insert into table result of query from another scheme?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have two schemes. Each scheme of course has a different name. But the tables and the fields of each table in both schemes have identical names.

I want to query data from tables from the first scheme to insert the results into the second schemes table.

Q: Is this possible?

My small tests give me syntax errors but it is not clear what is wrong exactly.

My query from the second scheme is similar to this simple query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT table1.column1
FROM scheme1.table1
```

The first line (insert) is in scheme2. The second and third lines are from scheme1. But this is not working.

Q: How to make a query from two different schemes that both have identical table names and table fields names.

P.S. I know this design choice not ideal. But I found myself in this situation. It is not a long-term production database but for research data. I need to query from both schemes.

**EDIT:**

The teinsert into test2.t1.col1 
select t1.col1 from test1.t1;st query is:

```
insert into test2.t1.col1 
select t1.col1 from test1.t1;
```

The schemes are: `test1` and `test2`
The tables are: `test1.t1` and `test2.t1`
the columns are: `test1.t1.col1` `test2.t1.col1`

The query result is:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.col1  select t1.col1 from test1.t1' at line 1
```

Comment: In your from statemetn you reference your schema as schema1.table1, but on your insert you do not have a schema.  You need to make that schema2.table1 for your insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column count must match:

```
INSERT INTO t2
    (a,b,c)   -- You intend to provide 3 columns per row
  SELECT
    x,y,z     -- This list must have 3 columns, too.
  FROM t1 ...
```

Normally, the number of columns in t2 is expected to be the same, too.  But this is not a requirement.  Leaving out a column (in both the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`) leads to handling of the value as `NULL`.

With an `AUTO_INCREMENT id`, you might do:

```
INSERT INTO t2
    (id,b,c)
  SELECT
    NULL,y,z     -- automatically provide `id`
  FROM t1 ...
```

or this has the same effect:

```
INSERT INTO t2
    (b,c)
  SELECT
    y,z
  FROM t1 ...
```